# Can you use ASP.NET membership in your own database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

Is there another (preferable simpler) way of including membership tables in your own database other than writing your own provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can deploy the MS membership provider into whatever database you like (provided that it uses SQL Server). You can use the command-line tool aspnet_regsql.exe (located in the framework folder) to create the tables and procedures used by the membership provider. You won't be able to use your own tables without changing the either the stored procedures or writing your own provider but you can extend the tables (for example adding foreign keys to the users table or adding columns).

I believe you can setup a connection string in the web.config and deploy the tables via web interface but I'm not entirely sure about that. However I am absolutely sure that once deployed you can tweak your existing database with the web tool if you setup the connection string.

Comment: My problem is that on the target server I have one mssql database, so I need to store there whole data and I want to use membership. I won't change table structure, the two things I need is: 1) have all tables (aspnetdb and own) in one database 2) be able to refer to UserID and so on

Comment: Assuming that you know how to use the console tool you should have any problem pointing it at an existing database.

Comment: I would just like to point out because I've hit the issue several times. If you script the database you should script not only the table structure and the stored procedures but also the data in the table that stores the version of the provider. Otherwise when you restore the database from scripts the provider will complain that it has a wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply by editing the web.config file  as follows

```
<system.web>
....

<membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add connectionStringName="yourConnectionStringName" applicationName="YourAppName" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="3" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Clear" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>

</system.web>
```

Then run the asp.net configuration  or aspnet_regsql.exe